Spyder stdout not being flushed
Updated with complete example.  I'm running this in Spyder but it's been noted in comments that this works as expected from a windows command prompt.
I have the following:
import sys
import os    
class Portfolio:
    
    @classmethod
    def menu(cls):
        print("Main Menu")
            
        p = Portfolio()
        p.clear_screen()           
        p.transaction()
            
    def clear_screen(self):
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print(flush=True) 
        sys.stdout.flush()      
        
    def transaction(self):           
        print("Transaction Menu")    

if __name__ == "__main__" :  
    Portfolio.menu()   

When I run this the screen clears AFTER not BEFORE transaction() is run.  How can I correct that?

Running this prints 'Main Menu', clears the screen, then prints 'Transaction Menu'.  It doesn't clear the screen after.

I'm running this in spyder and it does clear the screen after transaction() is called

That wasn't mentioned in the question and is important.  I'm running in a Windows command prompt.

didn't realize there would be a difference.  I'll add it to the question

I don't have Spyder so can't reproduce.  It isn't just opening a command window, running, then closing the window, is it?  If so add a pause like input('press enter to quit') or some such.
